# XML has empty body?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to working with XML and am editing a layout in my Android app and it is giving me the error "XML has empty body" is anyone able to tell me what I have done wrong? This is my code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/orange"></solid>


<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/orange"></stroke>

<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="15dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="15dp"></padding>

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:radius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:topRightRadius="12dp" />
```

Thanks

Edit: had to add spaces to make first 2 lines appear...

Comment: For some reason it didn't paste me entire code. Before that code it has: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"> and after it it has </shape>

Comment: you can edit that change into the OP by clicking the "edit" link under the tags

Comment: Thanks Panini, when I click edit it is actually showing those two lines but it does not seem to display them in the final version?

Comment: looks like your line breaks might be a bit strange

Comment: Is this a layout or a style. If it is a layout then is empty because you have not inserted a layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It appears to have worked by getting rid of the closing tags and replacing them with the self closing tags:

```
<solid android:color="@color/orange" />


<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/orange" />

<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="15dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="15dp" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:radius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:topRightRadius="12dp" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace the tag

```
<solid android:color="@color/orange"></solid>
```

instead of

```
<solid android:color="@color/orange"/>
```

//like wise all tags

Answer (score 2):

Replacing 
**< include layout = "@layout/layout> < /include>** with:
 **< include layout = "@layout/layout />** worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just place the closing tag on a new line, for example replace:

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
```

with:

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/white">
</solid>
```

Answer (score 0):

all Android XML layout files need to start with the line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

so your file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle>
    <solid android:color="@color/orange"></solid>


    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/orange"></stroke>

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:top="15dp"></padding>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:radius="1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topRightRadius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks have just tried this but the error still remains

Answer (score 0):

the second  must be written two lines down.just put the cursor before the second  and the problem is solved.